# Installed VS2017 and cannot remove FileSystem Source Checking Icons

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I installed VS2017 community yesterday to test some dynamic C++ compiling but it did not end up being the solution I needed. I uninstalled VS2017 a few hours later however it did not remove the file system modifications it made. Now all the folders that are bound to git projects show up with either checkbox's or questions marks etc.

How can I turn off this feature?

[image]

Comment: uninstall TortoiseGit

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't show having that installed

Comment: any other tortoise tool installed? look in Taskmanager if TGitCache.exe is running

Comment: @magicandre1981 Nope not running at all. It all started after that VS2017 install.

Comment: run vs 2017 installer and remove any Git tools that the VS setup offers under individual components.

Comment: also in the root folder of the source, open the folder properties and look if you see a git/subversion tab